# How to initialize remote state in Terraform?

Tags: terraform, minio

I am trying to configure a Minio/S3 backend for `remote_state`. However, I receive the error message `No stored state was found for the given workspace in the given backend.` and I fail to understand why. Of course there is no state found as I haven't created one yet.

I run `terraform init`, then `terraform plan -input=false -out=myplan` which works if I don't use `remote_state` but shows the above error when I do.

EDIT: I was able to get through the first steps by using `-refresh=false`. But this doesn't seem to be a solution. If no state file is available I expect Terraform to treat it as a new deployment and create one.

Comment: Seems like a dumb error message. If you create the state locally and then configure the remote backend, `terraform init` should offer you to migrate your current state to remote.

Comment: This is what I am not understanding, 'create state locally'. You mean, init locally, then plan locally, then apply and then migrate the resulting state to the remote backend?

Comment: As a kind of troubleshooting step, yes. It should then offer you to migrate the exisitng state into the remote backend, after you've configured a new remote state.
Might show what's actually wrong with the bucket you're trying to use as a remote state.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to run `terraform init` to migrate the local state file to the remote host.

For a step by step guide you can follow the example in the [official docs](https://www.terraform.io/docs/cloud/migrate/index.html), with step `#6` being the actual step that migrates the local `tfstate` to the remote host.

Comment: Alright, but this means that I cannot use a remote state in an empty terraform repo?

Comment: The problem was that I used state as data source not terraform setting... https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/terraform.html#configuring-a-terraform-backend

Answer (score 0):

I really missed this documentation here: https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/terraform.html#configuring-a-terraform-backend

Just read about remote state, thought it would come in handy and followed this documentation: https://www.terraform.io/docs/state/remote.html

Which points as an example to this: https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/terraform/d/remote_state.html

The first one did the trick.